# Trying to find guild member list for discord guilds

Tags: python, discord

```
async def get_guild_members(guild_id: int):
    guild = bot.fetch_guild(guild_id)
    
    return guild.member_count

get_guild_members(789226204980707409)
```

I'm using this code to try to find the memeber count of a guild on discord. WHen I run it it returns
<coroutine object get_guild_members at 0x7ffd518ef4c0>
What does this mean? How do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This problem stems from your lack of knowledge of [`asyncio`](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/). You don't call asynchronous functions like regular functions but rather use `asyncio.run(coro())` or the `await coro()` syntax inside another async function.

**REGULAR FUNCTION**

```py
def main():
    pass

main()
```

**ASYNCIO FUNCTION**

```py
import asyncio

async def get_guild_members(guild_id: int):
    guild = await bot.fetch_guild(guild_id)
    
    return guild.member_count

member_count = asyncio.run(get_guild_members(78922624980707409))
```

Comment: Thanks! When I run this though, I get the error "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop". I'm running on Jupyter. Is this why?

Comment: you need to `await get_guild_members()` in jupyter notebook as jupyter notebook uses it's own event loop constantly i believe

Comment: Thanks so much. It's working now!